# How to restructure daily time series by distinct column values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have daily time series data by different counties in US, which is covid cases daily time series, I want to restructure/reshape it in order to use it with other time series data that I have. So I tried `groupby` operation to regroup the time series, but I got value error as follow:

> ValueError: No axis named county_state for object type DataFrame

I am not sure using `groupby` is the right move to take. Can anyone suggest possible way of doing this right in pandas? Any idea?

**current attempt**

Here is the [reproducible data on gist](https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/f372d7a05e1a63732665fad0c7c754d0). Here is the my current attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("df.csv")
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.groupby('date', 'county_state')['cases', 'deaths'].unstack().reset_index()
```

but above attempt is not working, which cause `ValueError` instead. Can anyone suggest how to make this right?

**desired output**

Here is structure of output of my expected dataframe, no need to use aggregate by `cases` or `deaths`.

```
    date    fips    cases   deaths  county_state
1/26/2020   4013    1   0   Maricopa_Arizona
1/27/2020   4013    5    0  Maricopa_Arizona
1/28/2020   4013    7    0  Maricopa_Arizona
...         
9/02/202    4013    2333  100     Maricopa_Arizona
1/26/2020   6037    1   0   Los Angeles_California
1/27/2020   6037    15    2  Los Angeles_California
1/28/2020   6037    20    4  Los Angeles_California
...
9/02/202    6037    10001  200     Los Angeles_California
```

How to achieve my expected output above? Any way to get this right in pandas?

Comment: Could you please explain the logic?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma idea is I want to make long dataframe where it should be restructured by each county along the date. I made mockup for my desired output above. Any idea? current answer is not doing any new w.r.t to actual dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gives you the output you wanted:

`df.groupby(['fips', 'county_state', 'date']).sum().reset_index()[["date", "fips", "cases", "deaths", "county_state"]]`

EDIT:
The data frame was read in like this:

`df = pd.read_csv("https://gist.github.com/jerry-shad/f372d7a05e1a63732665fad0c7c754d0/raw/425b91083519adae00056aac3b25dcb3cfda42bc/df.csv", sep="\t").drop(columns=["Unnamed: 5"])`

Results:

```
date    fips    cases   deaths  county_state
0   1/26/2020   4013    1   0   Maricopa_Arizona
1   1/27/2020   4013    1   0   Maricopa_Arizona
2   1/28/2020   4013    1   0   Maricopa_Arizona
3   1/29/2020   4013    1   0   Maricopa_Arizona
4   1/30/2020   4013    1   0   Maricopa_Arizona
... ... ... ... ... ...
7456    8/7/2020    55081   242 2   Monroe_Wisconsin
7457    8/8/2020    55081   242 2   Monroe_Wisconsin
7458    8/9/2020    55081   243 2   Monroe_Wisconsin
7459    9/1/2020    55081   286 2   Monroe_Wisconsin
7460    9/2/2020    55081   290 2   Monroe_Wisconsin
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this to import the CSV correctly, the CSV has some issues with space at the end of each line and your separator is ' '. Probably best to split the county and state into separate columns, sort them and then drop them:

```
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', sep='    ')
df.drop(columns='Unnamed: 5', inplace=True)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['state'] = df['county_state'].str.split('_').str[1]
df['county'] = df['county_state'].str.split('_').str[0]
df.sort_values(by=['state', 'county', 'date'], inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=['state', 'county'], inplace=True)
print(df)

            date   fips  cases  deaths      county_state
0    2020-01-26   4013      1       0  Maricopa_Arizona
2    2020-01-27   4013      1       0  Maricopa_Arizona
4    2020-01-28   4013      1       0  Maricopa_Arizona
6    2020-01-29   4013      1       0  Maricopa_Arizona
8    2020-01-30   4013      1       0  Maricopa_Arizona
...         ...    ...    ...     ...               ...
7280 2020-08-29  55081    280       2  Monroe_Wisconsin
7325 2020-08-30  55081    281       2  Monroe_Wisconsin
7370 2020-08-31  55081    282       2  Monroe_Wisconsin
7415 2020-09-01  55081    286       2  Monroe_Wisconsin
7460 2020-09-02  55081    290       2  Monroe_Wisconsin

[7461 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: @NYC Coder your output is not right, he specified his desired output's structure above.

Comment: @Adam I don't understand the expected output, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Jared Can you explain how the desired output is different from this output?

Comment: @NYC Coder I want to make long dataframe where it should be restructured by each county along the date. I made mockup for my desired output above. Any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get it. You want to sum the deaths and cases by county and date?

Comment: @NYC Coder no need to aggregate at the moment, so no need to take sum of `cases` and `deaths`, just restructure it way that I want above. Any possible update? Thanks

Comment: Isn't that just sorting by county? So you want to sort by state and date?

Comment: @NYCCoder I think he is not trying to make aggregation on `cases` column, I think he is trying to regroup original dataframe by each `county_state` along `date`. that's his intention from the post.

Comment: Check edited answer and see if that is what you want

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential solution:

- Read the csv through `pd.read_csv` and make `date` the `index` of df directly and `drop` the unnecessary column.

```
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', parse_dates=['date'],index_col=['date']) 
df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 5'], inplace=True)
```

- Use `groupby` together with `resample`.

```
df.groupby(['fips','county_state']).resample('1D').sum()
```

Output (Only the head of the `dataframe`):

```
                                 fips  cases  deaths
fips county_state     date                           
4013 Maricopa_Arizona 2020-01-26  4013      1       0
                      2020-01-27  4013      1       0
                      2020-01-28  4013      1       0
                      2020-01-29  4013      1       0
                      2020-01-30  4013      1       0
```

Comment: I don't do aggregation for now, should I remove it? what is 1D stand for, why? BTW, this attempt gives typeError.

Comment: @Adam  I have just updated the answer. 1D just stands for 1 Day. I prefer resample just because it allows easy grouping of the timeseries. Now you shouldn't `typeError`.